# C - how to copy a struct using pointers to the struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Normally making a copy of a struct is as simple as just using the = operator and the compiler generates code to copy the struct over for you. However, for this part the function has to return a pointer to a struct so I've been working with that the whole time only to get to a part where I realized that everything I tried wasn't copying the struct over correctly.

A basic example of my problem is

```
typedef struct command_stream *command_stream_t;
command_stream_t ty = (command_stream_t) malloc(sizeof(struct command_stream));
command_stream_t yy;

do some code
//ty contains a variable words which is an array of strings

*yy = *ty;
 ty->words = NULL; //set to null to see if yy still contains a copy of the struct
 printf("%s", yy->words[0]);
```

I get a segmentation fault here. However, if I change it so it isn't a pointer

```
typedef struct command_stream command_stream_t

yy=ty;
ty.words = NULL;
printf("%s", yy.words[0]);
```

This works just fine! I'm not entirely sure how I should do the same thing for pointers, and I don't really want to go back and change 500+ codes of lines...

Comment: You're never allocating any memory for `*yy`.

Comment: Note: hiding a pointer behind a typedef like this is extremely confusing, and likely to lead to bugs...

Comment: I know right, but that part of the assignment I'm not allowed to modify. And thanks to everyone else! I just assumed that since yy was a pointer I could get away with just pointing it at an existing object.

Comment: The confusion is exacerbated by code like `command_stream_t ty = (command_stream_t) malloc(sizeof(struct command_stream));`, which also obliterates the opacity of the typedef.  It is much clearer to write: `struct command_stream *ty = malloc( sizeof *ty );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `yy` pointer is never initialized.

You should allocate enough memory there to hold the struct and then either copy with * like you did, or use `memcpy` with the pointers and size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
struct command_stream* ty = (struct command_stream*) malloc(sizeof(struct command_stream));

/* do things with the struct */

struct command_stream ty_val = *ty;
struct command_stream yy = ty_val;
```